# Realization of strong type

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $M$ be a monster model of a stable theory $T$ in a countable language, and assume that $A$ is an infinite algebraically closed set and that $A\subseteq{N}$ is an $|A|^+$ saturated model. Let $A\subseteq{A_0}\subseteq{N}$ be s.t. $|A_0|=|A|+\aleph_0$. I want to show that there exists a realization $A_0'$ of $\text{stp}(A_0/A)$ inside of $N$ with $A_0'\overset{\vert}{\smile}_{A}A_0$.

I'm not sure how to obtain this. It should reduce to a compactness argument that adds constant symbols for elements of $A_0'$ and then states it realizes the strong type of $A_0'$ over $A$ and doesn't $A_0'$ fork with $A_0$ over $A$. I'm not sure how to code in the latter part of the argument: i.e. $A_0'$ and doesn't fork with $A_0$ over $A$. How would I go about proving this?

I tried to assume that the statement failed: then the failure should be witnessed by a formula. But I can't really see any way to proceed after that. The other option seems to be to treat $N$ itself as a monster model and argue that since it's a monster model that the theorems of stability apply to prove the statement (or some variant thereof). But this seems to be asking for too much of $N$....

Comment: Isn't this just the existence of nonforking extensions? $tp(A_0'/A_0)$ is a nonforking extension of $tp(A_0/A)$ (assuming wlog $A$ is algebraically closed).

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan, Yes, but why does it need to be inside of $N$?

Comment: By saturation? The way you phrase it, $N$ may not be sufficiently saturated if $A$ is finite. In such a case it need not be in $N$. But otherwise I think $N$ is sufficiently saturated.

Comment: @Ah, that looks like it should work. Would you like to turn this in to  a complete answer? Further I'm assuming $A$ is infinite. I'll update the question.